# PHP user rating based on post and read count

Tags: php, rating

Im trying to get user stars based on their post and read count.

1. 0 post, 0 reads – 0 stars
2. 3 post, 3,000 reads – 1 star
3. 15 post, 15,000 reads – 2 star
4. 25 post, 30,000 reads – 3 star
5. 35 post, 40,000 reads – 4 star
6. 50 post, 70,000 reads – 5 star

code:

```
$read = 15000;
$news = 13;


if($read < 3000 || $news < 3){
    echo '0';   
}
else if(($read >= 3000 & $news >= 3)
        && ($read < 15000 & $news < 15)){
    echo '1';
}
else if(($read >= 15000 & $news >= 15)
        && ($read < 30000 & $news < 25)){
    echo '2';
}
else if(($read >= 30000 & $news >= 25)
        && ($read < 40000 & $news < 35)){
    echo '3';
}
else if(($read >= 40000 & $news >= 35)
        && ($read < 70000 & $news < 50)){
    echo '4';
}
else if($read >= 70000 & $news >= 50){
    echo '5';
}
```

this does not work well..

Comment: What is the result ? You can also use "AND" and "OR" in PHP ! in place of "&" and "||" and better to use "elseif" in PHP than "else if" :p

Comment: i tried that it does not really work..

Comment: What is  the result, they are not solutions, just some suggestions :)

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't match any if else state.

Comment: Just change this part in all conditions : && ($read < 15000 & $news < 15)) with : && ($read <= 15000 & $news <= 15))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this,

```
<?php

$read = 50;
$post = 44;


if($post >= 50 && $read >= 70000){
    echo "5 stars";
}else if($post >= 35 && $read >= 40000){
    echo "4 stars";
}else if($post >= 25 && $read >= 30000){
    echo "3 stars";
}else if($post >= 15 && $read >= 15000){
    echo "2 stars";
}else if($post >= 3 && $read >= 3000){
    echo "1 stars";
}else{
    echo "0 stars";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code "doesn't work" now because it does not match any of your if else statements. If you change your code to this, it should work with the given arguments:

```
$read = 15000;
$news = 13;


if($read < 3000 || $news < 3){
    echo '0';   
}
else if(($read >= 3000 & $news >= 3)
        && ($read <= 15000 & $news <= 15)){
    echo '1';
}
else if(($read >= 15000 & $news >= 15)
        && ($read <= 30000 & $news <= 25)){
    echo '2';
}
else if(($read >= 30000 & $news >= 25)
        && ($read <= 40000 & $news <= 35)){
    echo '3';
}
else if(($read >= 40000 & $news >= 35)
        && ($read <= 70000 & $news <= 50)){
    echo '4';
}
else if($read >= 70000 & $news >= 50){
    echo '5';
}
```

I reproduced it in an angular fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10941/

Your second statements should also check for `<=`